# Scheme: mapping let and set! onto lists

Tags: mapping, scheme, syntax-error, racket

I am trying to map let and set! onto lists something like this:

```
(map (lambda (x) (let ((x #f)))) <list>)
```

and

```
(map set! <list1> <list2>)
```

But, of course, neither is working.

Is there a way to do this?  Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

---

The real problem is that I am trying to find a way to pattern match letrec.  I need to be able to pattern match:

```
(letrec ((var val) ...) expr0 expr1 ...)
```

and convert it -- using match-lambda -- to an equivalent call using only let and set!  This is the template I am trying to emulate:

```
(letrec ((var val) ...) expr0 expr1 ...)
```

==>

```
(let ((var #f) ...)
(let ((temp val) ...)
(set! var temp) ...
(let () expr0 expr1 ...)))
```

The problem is translating this into syntax that match-lambda accepts.  Here is what I was working on, assuming there was a way to accomplish the original question:

```
(match-rewriter (`(letrec((,<var> ,<val>) ...) ,<expr> ...)
                   `((map (λ (x) (let ((x #f)))) ,<var>)
                      (let ((temp ,<val>)))
                        (map set! ,<var> temp)
                        (let () ,@<expr>))))
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. Short of using `eval`, variable names are generally not allowed to be dynamic (basically anything that isn't a symbol literal). This is by design.

If your variable names really are literals, and you just want a way to bind multiple variables at once, you can use `let-values` ([SRFI 11](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-11/srfi-11.html)) or extended `let` ([SRFI 71](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-71/srfi-71.html)).

---

Edit to match OP's edit: What you want to do sounds like [the `letrec` definition given here](http://www.scheme.com/tspl3/syntax.html#./syntax%3as39). However, that macro uses `syntax-case`, not `match-lambda` or the like. You may be able to use it as a starting point, though.

Comment: @Schemer: You mean you want to do something like this? http://www.scheme.com/tspl3/syntax.html#./syntax:s39 (see the `letrec` definition in the example). But, that uses `syntax-case`, not `match-rewriter`.

Comment: Unfortunately I am constrained to use match-lambda.  I need to write a rule letrec→let&set! that pattern matches calls to letrec using match-lambda and returns an equivalent rule that uses only let and set.  The problem seems to be that the match-lambda syntax just isn't as powerful as define-syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you want:

```
(define (rewrite-letrec l)
  (match l
    [(list 'letrec (list (list vars rhss) ...)
           exprs ...)
     (let ([tmps (map (λ _ (gensym)) vars)])
       `(let (,(map (λ (v) `(,v #f)) vars))
          (let (,(map (λ (tmp rhs) `(,tmp ,rhs)) tmps rhss))
            ,@(map (λ (v t) `(set! ,v ,t)))
            (let () ,@exprs))))]))
```

There are several differences here.  One is that the `let`s are nested.  Second, we're *constructing* code, not trying to run it.